# Dynamic load a .NET assembly with some other dll dependency

Tags: c#, plugins, dll, .net-assembly, dynamic-loading

I want to create a plugin engine for my app, but I have a problem: How can I load a .Net assembly  (Actually my plugin) which has some dependency to other assembly.

For example I want to load `A.DLL` and `A.DLL` need to `B.dll` or `C.dll` and so on to run. The `A.dll` has two method such as `A()` and `B()`. And `A()` or `B()` use some method of `B.dll` or `C.dll`.

What should I do to dynamically load `A.DLL` and call `A()` or `B()`?

Comment: `Assembly.Load` should do that if all dependent assemblies exist. What problems you're facing?

Comment: Take a look at [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Krumia is right, what you are looking for is already in .NET and is called 'MEF'. Try it, it's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Use AssemblyResolve event in the current AppDomain:

To load DLLs:

```
string[] dlls = { @"path1\a.dll", @"path2\b.dll" };
foreach (string dll in dlls)
{
    using (FileStream dllFileStream = new FileStream(dll, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
         BinaryReader asmReader = new BinaryReader(dllFileStream);
         byte[] asmBytes = asmReader.ReadBytes((int)dllFileStream.Length);
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(asmBytes);
    }
}
// attach an event handler to manage the assembly loading
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
```

The event handler checks for the name of the assembly and returns the right one:

```
private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    AppDomain domain = (AppDomain)sender;
    foreach (Assembly asm in domain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        if (asm.FullName == args.Name)
        {
            return asm;
        }
    }
    throw new ApplicationException($"Can't find assembly {args.Name}");
}
```